# Buttons on android webviews that do not react

Tags: android, webview

I am using a webview in my application. The webview works correctly, but I have a problem. When loading a page, it has a side menu button that if you press it while the web is doing its first load, it does not react or work. It only works when the web is fully loaded.

I'm looking for information but I can not find anything about it.

I make a very basic use of the webview:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(Hola.client);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

I have tried using the parameter:

```
mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

But without success .. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please share your activity class and xml

Comment: in this case I do not see the need, I think that with these data is enough to understand the query

Comment: Okay, Good but just wanted to see where have you initialize menu & webviews ... no worries

Comment: that is probably because the code that processes button press loads the last. So before it loads, nobody knows what should be done when button is clicked.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I'm going to investigate that possibility. Thank you very much